# Storing a real matrix - fl notation

Tags: matrices, real-numbers, floating-point

I have two matrix $A$ and $B$ and $fl(A), fl(B)$ denote the stored version them, respectively.
Let $fl(AB)$ be the stored version of the product of $A$ and $B$.
Is it true that $fl(AB) = fl(A) * fl(B)$?

Intuitively, I don't think this is the case since the right hand side must have more error, correct?

But I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: By "stored version" you mean with each element rounded to the nearest representable number in some finite floating-point representation?

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes. $fl(A) = A + E$ where $|E| <= u|A|$ and $u$ is the machine precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are usually two meanings of $\mathrm{fl}(\cdot)$. The first one is the representation of an object (matrix, vector) in the finite precision arithmetic. So for an $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $\mathrm{fl}(A)\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is what you call the "stored version" of $A$. But when you write $\mathrm{fl}(AB)$, it normally means the computed result of the product of $A$ and $B$, which can be quite different from $\mathrm{fl}(A)\mathrm{fl}(B)$.

Consider a matrix
$$
A=B=\pmatrix{10^{-2} & 10^2 \\ 10^1 & 10^0}
$$
and the 2-digit floating point arithmetic with base 10. We have $\mathrm{fl}(A)=\mathrm{fl}(B)=A=B$ (each mantisa contains only a single digit) but
$$
\mathrm{fl}(AB)=\pmatrix{10^3 & 10^2 \\ 10^1 & 10^3}\neq \pmatrix{10^3 & 1.01\cdot 10^2\\1.01\cdot 10^1&1.001\cdot 10^3}=AB.
$$

In general, usual implementations of the matrix product (it is not true, e.g., for the Strassen algorithm) give for $A\in\mathrm{R}^{m\times n}$ and $B\in\mathrm{R}^{n\times p}$ that
$$
|\mathrm{fl}(AB)-AB|\leq\gamma_n|A||B|, \quad \gamma_n:=\frac{nu}{1-nu},
$$
where $u$ is the unit roundoff. See, e.g., Section 3.5 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=7J52J4GrsJkC).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an example of what the OP asks. When $fl(A)=A$ and $fl(B)=B$ then necessarily $fl(AB)=fl(fl(A)fl(B))$ too. You're just showing that rounding may be necessary after the multiplication, not that rounding _before_ the multiplication matters.

Comment: @HenningMakholm OP asks if $\mathrm{fl}(AB)=\mathrm{fl}(A)\mathrm{fl}(B)$. I just showed that it is not true no matter whether the error is due to rounding in the matrix multiplication or in storing (both give the same result for this simple example).